# How to make this dropdown display outside of container

Tags: html, css

If you look at this link you will see a small Actions link top left, I have added a Jquery built dropdown to it but its being clipped by the wrapping element . Is there anyway to get this dropdown to display outside the section without significantly altering the html structure? I've tried altering the z-index ect but to no avail.

http://sugarcrmdev.co.uk/AdminLTE-master/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `overflow: auto` causes the problem. You have to scroll to see the submenu. Would this solves your problem:

```
.content-header {
 overflow: visible;
 min-height: 45px;
}
```

You still have the original height of your bar, but the submenu would be visible.

And to fix the resulting layout problem in mobile view you could add a

```
.headerList:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

No need for media queries. Can be used for desktop view as well.

Comment: Hmm that does seem to solve it. That easy eh cant believe I never thought of it. Ill test further

Comment: It seems to mess up on widths below 766px. I need it work in responsive design view also.

Comment: Sorry, didn't watch for mobile variant. Updated my solution and added a style for the `.headList` container.